# Can't Create Project or Solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, solution

So I can't seem to be able to create any new projects or solutions. I can navigate and open existing solutions but cannot create any new solutions. All help is appreciated. See screenshot below:

[image: Shot of my VS instance]

Comment: It looks like has something to do with you source control... are you en some team foundation solution? or something alike?

Comment: Could you add the full text from your output pane? I see "unable to create..." but there's more. Could be a clue. (You may be in need of a repair/reinstall.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some how I was stuck in "Project Management mode!"

Don't know how I got there, but it was hell.

I reset my settings and it was all good.

You can do that by going to Tools > Import & Export Settings > Reset all settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I changed my project location, template location and item templates location to a local drive that VS could find.  This seemed to fix my problem.  These settings can be found under Tools->Options.  Select projects and Solutions and then General.

Answer (score 1):

Small workaround: simply press Ctrl+Shift+N and 'New Project' window will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try going to Tools>Options>Source Control then change it to none and see if it works. It seems like you are using TFS or something and not allowed to add new projects to the source control.

Answer (score 0):

The Way I got around this was the basically the same as Stag, but in 2010 the reset all settings can be found under Help> Import & Export settings> Reset All Settings

Answer (score -1):

Have you stopped debugging?
If you are not sure, try this:
Debug->Stop debugging
(or)
Ctrl+F5

Then you can create New Project